# Prove that there is an interval of length $\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: calculus

> Assume $M > 0$ and $f'(x) \geq M$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Prove that there is an interval of length $\frac{1}{4}$ such that $\left |f(x) \right| \geq \frac{M}{4}$ for all $x \in I$.

Since $f$ is differentiable and continuous on $[0,1]$, there must exist a $c$ in $(0,1)$ such that $f'(c) = f(1)-f(0) \geq M$. That must mean there exists an interval $I'$ such that $\left |f(x) \right | \geq  \frac{M}{4}$ for all $x \in I'$ where $I'$ is an interval inside $[0,1]$ by the continuity of $f$. How do I find the length of this interval?

Comment: Hint: prove that either $f(1/4)\leq-M/4$ or $f(3/4)\geq M/4$.

Comment: @Wojowu Should I use the mean value theorem for that?

Comment: Yes, MVT is helpful for that.

Comment: @Wojowu I proved that $f(\frac{3}{4}) - f(0) \geq \frac{3}{4}M$. What else do I need?

Comment: Use MVT for $f(3/4)-f(1/4)$.

Comment: @Wojowu I get $f(\frac{3}{4}) - f(\frac{1}{4}) \geq \frac{M}{2}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37228/discussion-between-wojowu-and-puzzled417).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the answer on OP's request.

From MVT we have $f(\frac{3}{4})-f(\frac{1}{4})=f'(c)(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4})\geq \frac{M}{2}$. From MVT we also have that $f$ is increasing on $[0,1]$ (since its derivative is positive on this interval). Finally, we consider two cases.

1. If $f(\frac{1}{4})\leq-\frac{M}{4}$, then, since $f$ is increasing, $f(x)\leq-\frac{M}{4}$ for all $0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{4}$, so $|f(x)|\geq\frac{M}{4}$ for $x\in[0,\frac{1}{4}]$.
2. If $f(\frac{1}{4})>-\frac{M}{4}$ then $f(\frac{3}{4})\geq f(\frac{1}{4})+\frac{M}{2}>-\frac{M}{4}+\frac{M}{2}=\frac{M}{4}$ and we can deduce, similarly as above, from monotonicity that $f(x)>\frac{M}{4}$ for $\frac{3}{4}\leq x\leq 1$, so $|f(x)|>\frac{M}{4}$ for $x\in[\frac{3}{4},1]$.